# putting the answers of one parametric differential . eq. in another parametric differential eq

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have two  parametric diff eqs.  (just numerically could be solved) with boundary conditions in different points as I can not solve them in a system, I have one way that is to solve the first (which is independent) and put the parametric answers into the second(depended to the first one)  I was not successful in introducing the answers of the first into the second what should I do? my eqs are

```
E1 = ParametricNDSolve[{a A[x]^3 A'[x] + b A[x]^4 + (c+b) x^-3 == 0,A[1] == 1}, A, {x, .001, 
   1}, {a,b,c}]
```

A1[x,a,b,c]

```
E2 = ParametricNDSolve[{ B'[x] (A'[x]/A[x]+2) + b B[x]'' + (a+b)B[x] x^-3 == 0,
 B[.1] == 1,B[.01]==.1}, 
  B, {x, .001, 
   1}, {a,b,c}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your second equation, you want $B[x]''\to B''[x]$.

If you fix this you can solve your differential equations simultaneously:

```
solns = ParametricNDSolve[{
   a A[x]^3 A'[x] + b A[x]^4 + (c + b) x^-3 == 0,
   A[1] == 1,
   B'[x] (A'[x]/A[x] + 2) + b B''[x] + (a + b) B[x] x^-3 == 0,
   B[.1] == 1,
   B[1/100] == .1}, {A, B}, {x, .001, 1}, {a, b, c}]
```

and `someRule = Map[# -> RandomReal[{0, 1}] &, {a, b, c}]` with

```
Plot[{A[a, b, c][x], B[a, b, c][x], A[a, b, c]'[x]} /. solns /. 
   someRule // Evaluate, {x, .001, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> TraditionalForm /@ {A[x], B[x], B'[x]}]
```

yields

[image]

**Update** Modified function solution request to `ParametricNDSolve` to ask for `{A,B}` instead of `{A[x],B[X]...` for ease of soln use, applied in plot.

Comment: you right ,actually in the main code I've typed that correctly, I've found out that It does not solve two coupled differential   eqs. with different initial or boundary conditions simultaneously , at least they must have one common  boundary point

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?  In your example we have  different boundary conditions at time $t\in\{1,.1,.01\}$ i.e.  `A[1]` constrained, `B[.1]` constrained  and `B'[.01]` constrained. There doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: sol = ParametricNDSolve[{{-((3 (a + b) B[t])/(
       2 t^5 A[t]^2)) + (3/t + A'[t]/A[t]) B'[t] + B''[t] == 
     0, (a + b)/t^3 - A[t]^2 + m A[t]^4 + n t A[t]^3 A'[a] == 
     0}, {A[1] == 1, B[.001] == 5*10^-4, B'[.001] == 25*10^-5}}, {B, 
   B', A}, {t, 0.001, 1}, {a, b, c, d}]

Comment: thank again John for the consideration yes you're right  I could solve them 
I encounter problems when I put the answers into  some calculations in which I should  constrain a model. In that case it says that there are singularities and so on.... it seems that it is related to the equation itself not a problem with the solution. If you have time I'll send you the whole procedure

Comment: In your comment example your second equation doesn't look right. You have the derivative of $A$ evaluated at the point parameter $a$ i.e. $A'[a]$. This is a constant and could be replaced by a different parameter if necessary.  Please check your equations and maybe update the comment with the correct equation?

Comment: yes that was a mistake in typing it is A[t]

Comment: Differenital, `A'[t]`, right? like: `(a + b)/t^3 - A[t]^2 + m A[t]^4 + n t A[t]^3 A'[t] == 0` ?

Comment: yes that is right  actually I use two different versions of Mathematica, mine (on my PC) is 10.2 and the one on the computational computer  I use to run the codes is 9 ,the point is that the  later can not solve this eq. and has the problem I told( with boundary condition) but mine solves as you mentioned and does not have problem. I use this diff, equation in constraining  a cosmological model . I've found out that you work in cosmology  and that is a chance for me

Comment: @John Joseph M. Carrasco thanks for your solution, I used it in a problem of three functions interlinked about antibiotic resistance forecasting.